# Passing Html tags in ajax request using json format

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am Passing html tags in Ajax request using json format after replacing the tags with another characters like the following :

```
function changeJson(json) {
var ResultValue = "";
ResultValue = json;
var resultlength = ResultValue.length;

for (var wordlength = 0; wordlength < resultlength + 1; wordlength++) {
    ResultValue = ResultValue.replace("<", " l_ ");
    ResultValue = ResultValue.replace(">", " r_ ");
    ResultValue = ResultValue.replace("&", " and ");
}
return ResultValue;
```

}

is there is any other way to do it .

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing this replacing? It's not necessary.

Simply decorate the view model property with the [`[AllowHtml]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute. Just like that:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string SomeHtmlProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and then you could have a controller action that will handle the AJAX call:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    // do something with the model.SomeHtmlProperty here
    ...
}
```

and finally you could invoke this controller action using the $.ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somecontroller/someaction',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { someHtmlProperty: 'some value that could contain <, >, &, and whatever you want characters' },
    success: function(result) {
        // handle the results from your AJAX call here
    }
});
```

So as you can see, you don't really need to be writing functions called `changeJson` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Darin Dimitrov's solution is very good but if you want you could use [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) and decodeURIComponent to encode and decode the html string on client side. On server side, you could use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) to decode the encoded string.

```
encodeURIComponent("<a>& abc</a>");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9tYgm/